# The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

I'm outputting XML in CakePHP. But I'm getting this error when I put my XML into a validator:

```
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

I am using correct XML layout with `<?php echo $this->Xml->header(); ?>`  at the top then `<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>`

My results are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><response type='' outcome='true' message='Login successful!'>
    <user id='1234' total_number_of_completed_tasks='0' total_number_of_declined_tasks='0' total_number_of_passed_tasks='1' total_number_of_failed_tasks='1' reputation_points='99' deviant_points='0' />
        <tasks>
            <accepted>
                                <accepted_task id='4' type='Good' time_limit='500' details='Good accepted' />
                                <accepted_task id='5' type='OK' time_limit='660' details='Ok New task' />
                                <accepted_task id='9' type='Excellent' time_limit='2000' details='Great failed task' />
                                <accepted_task id='11' type='Your type' time_limit='222' details='Running and swimming all the way to Japan' />
                                <accepted_task id='7' type='Man' time_limit='744' details='My dirty task' />
                            </accepted>
            <pending>
                                <pending_task id='8' type='Women' time_limit='5151' details='Women new task' sender_id='11111' sent_date='2031-01-01 00:00:00' sender_name='Jae Choi' />
                            </pending>
            <completed>
                            </completed>
            <new>
                                <new_task id='5' type='OK' time_limit='660' details='Ok New task' />
                                <new_task id='8' type='Women' time_limit='5151' details='Women new task' />
                                <new_task id='4' type='Good' time_limit='500' details='Good accepted' />
                                <new_task id='10' type='Hello' time_limit='122' details='What is this?' />
                                <new_task id='3' type='Best' time_limit='880' details='Stop doing work!' />
                                <new_task id='11' type='Your type' time_limit='222' details='Running and swimming all the way to Japan' />
                                <new_task id='6' type='Great' time_limit='553' details='Great accepted task' />
                                <new_task id='7' type='Man' time_limit='744' details='My dirty task' />
                                <new_task id='9' type='Excellent' time_limit='2000' details='Great failed task' />
                            </new>
        </tasks>
</response>
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Have you check that the XML is generated without any blank space at the beggining?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

marmalad and El Boletaire Underave are right that you can't start with a space, but that's not the full story. According to [the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#proc-types), you can't have anything at all before the XML prolog.

Since you are using an XML declaration, you must start your file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" ...
```

In some cases, non-printing characters like [the byte order mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) can cause trouble by taking up the first few bytes of a file.

For a problem more specific to CakePHP, check to see that you don't have stray blank lines/whitespace at the start or end of your files (i.e. after your `?>` or before your `<?php`).

Answer (score 14):

As [El Boletaire Underave said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939426/the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed#comment9766153_7939426), check if the XML is generated without any blank space at the beggining.
this help me with my xml.

Answer (score 1):

Check Your XML file, it might start with a blank space. If your XML file begins with blank spaces this type of Exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

before `<?xml ?>`tag u should not have any space.
this tag should be on first line. 
this worked for me