# "manifest" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</manifest>"

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I get the following error but there is no problem in my manifest file.
I tried changing my project name but I got this error once I changed my project name. help me solving this error without changing the project name back to the old one.

My old project name was "radio" my new project name is "Msurvey"

My error:

```
[2014-02-15 17:35:02 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for H:\radio\AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "manifest" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</manifest>".
[2014-02-15 17:35:02 - radio] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

This is my manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.radio"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mobilesurvey"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Res"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_res" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Admin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.View"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.View1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view1" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Answers"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_answers" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Data"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_data" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Food"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_food" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Service"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_service" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Services"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_services" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Places"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_places" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Adminmenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_adminmenu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fullscreen"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Adminlogin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_adminlogin" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.radio.Report"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_report" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    </manifest>
```

I tried all the similar questions in stackoverflow for this error but none solved my problem. Also all myactivities have their background changed to black as default from white. plz help me solve this color change mainly. Plz help me solve it.

Comment: post ur xml file also

Comment: "radio", is it name of xml file???

Comment: radio is the old filename. the project name i first had. I changed it to Msurvey and thats when i got this error first

Comment: try clean and then build

Comment: how did u change the file name???

Comment: clicked on the project name on the left. The folder of the project, clicked F2 and renamed it.

Comment: I cant see in your code the starting manifest tag but anyway have you tried validating yor file with any xml validation tool?

Comment: I tried cleaning and I still get the same error

Comment: i got this error only after changing my project name. Plz note that. Also help me solving the background change I mentioned in the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to pass XML validation. You said you did a clean, but what could possibly be the problem is that maybe you're modifying the wrong AndroidManifest.xml. (There are versions of it dynamically created in your bin and gen folders for instance). Check that you're modifying the AndroidManifest.xml in the topmost folder of your project.

Comment: Ya I checked through it. I am trying to solve the correct one.. I have only one project in my eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

remove the stating blank before xml-manifest, see [The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939426/the-processing-instruction-target-matching-xxmmll-is-not-allowed)

Also you need to place user-permission tags before appliction tag.

Regards,

Alex

Comment: i placed the user-permission tags before appliction tag, thankz.. but still no change. also there is no blank space before or after the xml-manifest tag

Comment: hmm, in your post here it is:
' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'

Comment: Ya whats wrong with that? Im sorry I dont get it. as per the link u shared, thr shudnt be space either before or after <?xml and utf-8"?>